# Top result after ordering within a CALCULATED group by, in postgres, without nesting queries (subqueries, ctes...) in 2020?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried with `WINDOW functions`, `Ordered Sets`, `Hyptohetical Sets`, `DISTINCT ON`, `Grouping Sets` and I don't find the way to do this simple, without having to nest queries or using CTE precalculations... but I feel like it might exist

I just want to do something like this:

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(my_computed_field ORDER BY order_field) -- i.e, after the virtual grouping, output as the aggregation the internal row that comes first if ordering by another field that does not take part in the group by calculation
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY ABSOLUTELY_MONSTRUOUS_CALCULATION(my_computed_field)
```

without having to define the `ABSOLUTELY_MONSTRUOUS_CALCULATION(mycomputedfield)` part twice

Comment: Please don't change the nature of the question after an answer has been given. Write a new question instead.

Comment: I didn't, I just indicated that is optional but preferrably that the way of grouping allows counting (like the one in my example). The reason I didnt accept the answers is because it places an extra column in the results I did not asked for, although the question is good enough to approve it if nothing better comes

Comment: The extension of the answer is perfect though so I approve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (amc) ABSOLUTELY_MONSTRUOUS_CALCULATION(my_computed_field) as amc, my_computed_field
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY amc, order_field;
```

You can also do this as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (v.amc) my_computed_field
FROM mytable t CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (ABSOLUTELY_MONSTRUOUS_CALCULATION(my_computed_field) )) v(amc)
ORDER BY v.amc, order_field;
```

Comment: Very clever yet simple! Thanks. Did not think of the alias possibility! However, is there any way to silence first column without wrapping it up into a subselect?

Comment: Besides if I want to get the count(*) as well is not possible right? (I extended the question with that extra wish)